# Unable to deploy contract from inside another contract (works on Remix but returns revert on truffle)

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have been stuck on this for days trying to figure out why I am unable to create new contract instances from inside my parent. I am working on a larger project and couldn't understand so I created an extremely simple case to work on. Both my project and my simple project work correctly when using Remix Solidity Web but fail when I try to deploy using Truffle/testrpc. I downgraded from truffle 4.0.2 to 3.4.6. I am also using webpack to create the page.

Child.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;


contract child {
    int b;
    function child(int a) {
        b = a;
    }
    function getChild() returns (int abc) {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Parent.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import "./child.sol";

contract parent {

    uint pls;

    function parent(uint a) {
        pls = a;
    }

    function tester() returns (uint) {
        return pls;
    }

    function make() returns (child abc) {
        return new child(16); 
    }
}
```

Here is my simple deploy script: 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var parent = artifacts.require("./parent.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(parent,20);

};
```

Lastly here is my app.js. My html page is blank and I am only debugging using console.

```
// Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it.
import "../stylesheets/app.css";

// Import libraries we need.
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'

// Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
import metacoin_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/parent.json'

// MetaCoin is our usable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var MetaCoin = contract(metacoin_artifacts);

// The following code is simple to show off interacting with your contracts.
// As your needs grow you will likely need to change its form and structure.
// For application bootstrapping, check out window.addEventListener below.
var accounts;
var account;

window.App = {
  start: function() {
    var self = this;

    // Bootstrap the MetaCoin abstraction for Use.
    MetaCoin.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
      if (err != null) {
        alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
        return;
      }

      if (accs.length == 0) {
        alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
        return;
      }

      accounts = accs;
      account = accounts[0];
    });

    var temp;
    MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      temp = instance;
      console.log(instance.address);
      temp.make({from: account});
    }).then(function(abc) {
      console.log(abc);
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    })


  }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
  }

  App.start();
});
```

The error I get when trying to create a new contract for both my large project and this example project are the same:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.InvalidResponse (app.js:10361)
    at app.js:48279
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (app.js:50906)

I did a bit of debugging with truffle 4.0 before downgrading to see if it was the problem. Here is the error that I reached when it came to creating the new contract object:

Warning: The source code for one or more contracts could not be found.
This is the only source i was able to find this error: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/576

When I try this on remix browser solidity, my create function returns the address of the newly created contract with zero problems. Please help me, I have been banging my head against a wall for hours.

Comment: Did you try passing gas along with `from` in the make function call?

Comment: you can use web3.js to call the contract functions. It works without promises.

Comment: Adding gas fixed the problem, I was so used to using browser solidity that it completely slipped my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding in a gas parameter next to accounts.

```
  temp.make({from: account, gas : 50000000});
```